# Calculated Column in PowerBI With Filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem to solve similar to the example in the image below. I have the values of Column 1, 2 and 3, and want to get the calculated values exampled in Column 4. These are the number of times that the same number of Column 3 appears for different combinations of values from Column 1 and 2.
Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has as name 'table1', 
then the following dax statement will calculate column4.

```
Column4 = CALCULATE(countrows(Table1);filter(Table1;Table1[Column3]= EARLIER(Table1[Column3])))
```

Keep in mind that based on regional settings, you have to replace the ; with , in the example provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tryed your formula and didn´t work for my data. I also was trying before the formula: CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Column3]);ALLEXCEPT(Table1;Table1[Column1];Table1[Column2])) and I get this error: "A circular dependency was detected"

Comment: Can you give a dataset where the formula isn't working, and what result you expect?

Comment: Sorry, but yes, your answer is correct for my example. I forget to mention that I have another column with a timeline (from 1 to number of times from same values of column3). Taking in your formula and improved them I get the expected values: CALCULATE(countrows(Table1);filter(Table1;Table1[Column3]= EARLIER(Table1[Column3]));filter(Table1;Table1[Timeline]= EARLIER(Table1[Timeline]))).

Comment: I would avoid filtering the same table twice, 
just adjust your formula to :
CALCULATE(countrows(Table1);filter(Table1;Table1[Column3]= EARLIER(Table1[Column3]) && Table1[Timeline]= EARLIER(Table1[Timeline]))